# dom x path to grab href value

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have the following html

```
<div class="logo"><a href="/">***® text.<sup>TM</sup></a></div>
```

I would like to get the value of `href` with php dom xpath, how would I accomplish that?

This is what I have tried:

```
$anchors = $domXpath->query("//div[@class='logo']/a");
foreach($anchors as $a)
{ 
    print $a->nodeValue." - ".$a->getAttribute("href")."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: @u_mulder this is what I have tried, its in the question.

Comment: And what it shows you?

Comment: Im getting NOTICE: PHP message: Error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute()

Comment: No, you don't, see the fiddle: https://3v4l.org/gekuh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$link = $xpath->query('//div[@class="logo"]/a');
$link->getAttribute('href')
```

Comment: What is the output that you get?

Comment: I'm getting NOTICE: PHP message: Error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute()

Comment: Of course, because xpath returns collection of nodes and not a single node.